# Match two dataframes with similar columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

df1:

```
  Country_Name      Population_1991     Population_1992  
0 Colombia          33758337            34422569
1 Ecuador           3244345             324345455
2 France            362763732           372874749   
3 UK                327874738           375960889
```

df2:

```
    Period  Trade_Flow  Reporter    Partner Trade_Value
0   1991    Import      Colombia    France  230723392
1   1991    Import      Colombia    UK      1237364
2   1992    Import      Colombia    France  230723392
3   1992    Import      Colombia    UK      1237364
4   1991    Import      Ecuador     France  230723392
5   1991    Import      Ecuador     UK      1237364
6   1992    Import      Ecuador     France  230723392
7   1992    Import      Ecuador     UK      1237364
```

What I would like is to join df1 on df2 using the year and the Country_name. So from df2 for every row look at what is the Reporter country and match that with the Country_Name in df1. Take the value of population and add it in Reporter_pop column. Do the same for Partner_pop and so on.
The end result should look like this:

```
    Period  Trade_Flow  Reporter    Partner Trade_Value Reporter_pop Partner_pop
0   1991    Import      Colombia    France  230723392   33758337     362763732                   
1   1991    Import      Colombia    UK      1237364     33758337     327874738                 
2   1992    Import      Colombia    France  230723392   34422569     372874749  
3   1992    Import      Colombia    UK      1237364     34422569     375960889
4   1991    Import      Ecuador     France  230723392   3244345      362763732                 
5   1991    Import      Ecuador     UK      1237364     3244345      327874738              
6   1992    Import      Ecuador     France  230723392   324345455    372874749  
7   1992    Import      Ecuador     UK      1237364     324345455    375960889
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try This it will make df1 data format same as df2 :

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Country_name':['columbia',
                                 'ecuador', 'France'],
                'pop_1991':[123325,453233,645632],
                'pop_1992':[153232,478653,654324]})


df2=df.iloc[0:,[0,1]]
df2['Year']=1991
df2=df2.rename(columns={'pop_1991':'population'})
df3=df.iloc[0:,[0,2]]
df3['Year']=1992
df3=df3.rename(columns={'pop_1992':'population'})
df4=df2.append(df3,ignore_index=True)
```

Post this just merge you data basis year and country
Hope it helps u